# How to find variable/fields name from java source file?

Tags: java, string

I have read the source code and stored it's contents in a String like this:-
`String s="the code of the source file i am reading";`

I have tried few times

```
String s="source code";
String[] lines=s.split("\n");//split my source code into lines
```

After that i don't know how to find identifiers line by line

Comment: What do you mean by identifiers?

Comment: What do you try to archieve/What should your application be for?

Comment: like i have the code 
`int a=5;`
Here a is identifier or the name of variables given by user

Comment: We need more context to understand. Anyway there is a typo : s.split(...) return a String[]   not   String

Comment: @Vyncent i have edited my mistakes in code and i must hope to get valid answers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Java Reflection for this read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html),

```
 public class ReflectFoo2Class {
    public ReflectFoo2Class(){
            Foo2 f = new Foo2();
                    Field[] field;
            try {
                           field = f.getClass().getFields();
                           for(Field fa: field){
                                System.out.println(fa.getName());
                            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
        public static void main(String[]args){
            new ReflectFoo2Class();
        }
     }
class Foo2 {
        public String v = "";
        public String v1 = "";
        public String v2 = "";
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
}
```

Comment: I get you, I got mixed up with your "Identifier" thing

Comment: Thanks for giving me the idea of using reflection. But getFields() will give only public fields , i used getDeclaredFields().getName() to access all public , private , protected fields . Anyways thanks a lot :) @Sarz

Comment: Pleasure, Yes its just a beginning of Reflection.